# Why urllib.request.urlopen() works time-to-time?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, urllib

I try to write a parser based on `urllib` and `beautifulsoup` libraries, but don't understand why sometimes I get a request status 200, but sometimes 404 (with the same URL of course), moreover the URL which had been requested by `urllib` and returned 404 opens perfect manually via a browser.
Could anyone explain that behavior?

```
url = 'https://zakupki.gov.ru/epz/order/extendedsearch/results.html'
params = {'searchString': 'Сакубитрил',
         'morphology': 'on',
        'pageNumber': 1,
        'sortDirection': 'false',
        'recordsPerPage': '_10',
        'showLotsInfoHidden': 'false',
        'sortBy': 'UPDATE_DATE',
        'fz44': 'on',
        'fz223': 'on',
        'af': 'on',
        'ca': 'on',
        'pc': 'on',
        'pa': 'on',
        'currencyIdGeneral': -1,
        'publishDateFrom': '01.02.2021',
        'publishDateTo': '21.02.2021'}

def parser(url, params):
    
    attempt = 0 

    while attempt < 10:
        
        try: 
            data = urllib.parse.urlencode(params) 
            full_url = url + '?' + data
            with urllib.request.urlopen(full_url, timeout = 10) as response:
                the_page = response.read()
                soup = BeautifulSoup(the_page, 'html.parser')
                return soup
            
        except Exception: # don't forget replace Exception with something more specific
            attempt += 1
            time.sleep(5)
            continue

data = parser(url, params=params)
```

Comment: There is nothing to do with `urllib` because that is how the server replies. You may test it with `curl -s -o /dev/null -w "%{http_code}\n" 'https://zakupki.gov.ru/epz/order/extendedsearch/results.html?searchString=%D0%A1%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%B1%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB'` and see that it replies 200 or 404 from time to time.

Comment: do you mean the issue appears on a server side? if it so may be you know any workarounds?

Comment: _"do you mean"_; yes. _"workarounds?"_; you may repeat your request until you get status code `200`

Comment: a brute force option always is option :)

Comment: You may use browser automation tools ([Puppeteer](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer), [Selenium](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/)) if you want to mimic a real user or execute JavaScript.

Comment: I have thought about using selenium, but seems like it is not a good option, because the issue appears when I try to send a GET request to particular URL. May be if I will start parsing with the main page (zakupki.gov.ru) and then use selenium to type my request it would works. I have check.